# Linux: sendmail in a bash script

Tags: linux, sendmail

I need to send a filename, a timestamp of the file and its number of rows via mail if it contains over 1000 rows.

The ll -h is not working in my script (an error is thrown and the sent mail is blank), though it is working as a separate command.

**Not working:**

```
#!/bin/sh
pfad="/home/bspftp/script"
rows=1000
actualsize=$(wc -l <"$1")
if [ $actualsize -ge $rows ]; then
    echo "In the file $1 there are more than $rows rows"
    ll -h $pfad/$1 | sendmail my@mail.net #throws error: line 7: ll: command not found
else
    echo "In the file $1 there are less than $rows rows"
fi
```

I execute my script as below:

```
bash num_rows.sh ~/script/file.log
```

**Working:**

```
ll -h ~/script/file.log | sendmail my@mail.net
```

Comment: What does `type ll` output? I suspect `ll` is just an alias, and the script might not be aware of your bash aliases.

Comment: shell aliases, which `ll` almost certainly is, resolving to `ls -l`, are generally not available in non-interactive shell sessions, like the one running a script.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments! I was not aware of that! I changed the alias from `ll -h` to `ls -lh` in the script and that resolved the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the fullpath to `ll`or add it to your environment `PATH` variable.

You can where it is with `whereis ll`.